# Create X509 certificate from base64 CSR string and CA root certificate in c#

Tags: .net-core, bouncycastle, x509certificate2, ca, csr

I need to generate a certificate starting from the `base64` string value of a PEM encoded CSR and a CA root certificate.

The CA certificate is generated using `openssl` from the command line.

Given that [CertificateRequest api from .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest?view=net-6.0) does not provide a `.FromPemBase64String()` method, it is basically impossible to use it in my case. I have tried to find a solution using BouncyCastle library but most of the solutions I have found generate a CSR on the fly while I actually need it to be parsed from a string.

Currently my solution is to:

- store the CSR to a file (`test.csr`)
- programmatically run the following command:
  `openssl x509 -req -in test.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -passin pass:"password123" -CAcreateserial -out test.crt -days 730 -sha256`

Everything works fine but it would be great if I can find a programmatically way to do the same (including generating the CA on the fly so I don't have to add the files to the project).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I am currently using .NET6

Comment: You should use a specialized CA software. Generating certificates from the code never was a good idea.

Comment: There must be a way though 

Comment: Very helpful! thank you so much @bartonjs.

BTW Crypt32 I just need to do this in an integration test to test some business logic. I won't create certificates using custom CA in production 